# Issue with Visual Studio 2022 Intellisense Complete Word function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

1. Create an ASP.NET Core project. I created it using the new Empty template using .NET 6 but it shouldn't matter. I then compiled the app.
2. In program.cs, locate the line where the builder object is instatiated. Add it if it is not found.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

3. After the above added line, type the incomplete following line of code and then, with your cursor at end of the unfinished line, click the shortcut `control` + `space` to execute the menu command `Edit`->`Intellisense`->`Complete Word`

```
builder.Services.AddS
```

I expected the intellisense to pop up and pre-select "AddScoped" in the list. But it just sat there.

Intellise generally works but not always. This is one example where it doesn't, at least for me.

Does it work for you? Should it work as I described? I'm thinking so...

I'm using the following version if VS:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.4.0
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.4.0+33103.184
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Used Visual Studio Installer and executed a 'repair'. Everything works now!